# Как решить проблему с заполнением словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Из отдельных текстовых файлов, я беру данные, из одного в ключ из другого в значение, потом убираю ненужные апострофы и тп, и кидаю их словарь. Но при выполнение, значения ведут себя очень, странно. Думаю ошибка в том что я где то не перевел строку, но не могу понять где и как.

```
with open("R1.txt" , encoding='utf-8') as f:
    values = f.readlines()

with open ('R2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    keys = f.readlines()

two_values = ''.join(values)

three_value = two_values.replace("'", "")
four_values = three_value.replace("р." , "")
print(four_values)
market_all = {}
my_all = { 'Один\n':'3'}



for i in range(len(keys)):
    market_all[keys[i]] = four_values[i]

print (market_all)
print (my_all)

if int(market_all[keys[0]]) == int(my_all[keys[0]]):
     print ("Ok")
```

`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо из первого файла взять значение, из второго ключ, кинуть в словарь, и потом сравнивать значения одного ключа из моего словаря, и из того в котором хранятся ключи и значения которые пришли в текстовом документе.

```
market_all ={}
```

это словарь в который идут данные из текстовых документов, а

```
my_all={}
```

это мой словарь

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте отступы в коде

Comment: "значения ведут себя очень, странно" - в чем именно странность?

Comment: @insolor в первом словаре должно быть так {"Один\n" : 350000}, а по итогу каждый ключ принял часть одного значения

Comment: @gil9red исправил

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что у вас в файлах, и что конкретно вы хотите сделать

Comment: @insolor все указал, но стоит отметить что когда я читал по одной строке из текстовых файлов readline(), то все работало, но вот проблема появилась когда начал использовать readlines()

Comment: four_values у вас строка а не список. Возможно стоит сделать `four_values = four_values.splitlines()`

Answer (score 1):

Попробую натолкнуть Вас на мысль:

есть 2 исходника:

`keys.txt`

```html
Один
Два
Три
Четыре
Пять
```

и `values.txt`

```html
1000
2000
3000
4000
5000
```

код:

```py
    keys = open('./keys.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    values = open('./values.txt', encoding='utf-8')

    print({key: value for key, value in zip(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ''), keys.readlines()),
                                            map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ''), values.readlines()))})

    keys.close()
    values.close()
```

В результате даст:

```py
    # {'Один': '1000', 'Два': '2000', 'Три': '3000', 'Четыре': '4000', 'Пять': '5000'}
```

Если Вы хотите сохранить переводы строк в конце значений (честно не понимаю зачем) то можно просто убрать функцию их обрезающую:

```
print({key: value for key, value in zip(keys.readlines(), values.readlines())})
```

Что даст:

```
    # {'Один\n': '1000\n', 'Два\n': '2000\n', 'Три\n': '3000\n', 'Четыре\n': '4000\n', 'Пять\n': '5000\n'}
```

Ну и если я правильно понял задачу, то я решил бы ее так:
`teplate.txt`

```html
Один 1'000p.
Два 2'000p.
Три 30'000p.
Четыре 4'000p.
Пять 5'000p.
```

Собственно вариант решения:

```
import re
from sys import exit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keys = open('./keys.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    values = open('./values.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    template = open('./template.txt', encoding='utf-8')

    check = {key: value for key, value in zip(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ''), keys.readlines()),
                                              map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ''), values.readlines()))}

    clean = re.compile(r'[\D]')

    all_market = {key: clean.sub('', value) for key, value in 
                  [line.split() for line in template.readlines()]}

    error_count = 0

    for key in check:
        if key not in all_market:
            print(f'{key} не найден в проверяемом списке')
            exit(2)
        if check[key] != all_market[key]:
            error_count += 1
            print(
                f'{error_count} ------------------------------\n'
                f'Значения {key} не совпадают!!!\n'
                f'Значение в контрольном списке {check[key]}\n'
                f'Значение в проверяемом списке {all_market[key]}\n'
            )

    template.close()
    keys.close()
    values.close()
```

```
# 1 ------------------------------
# Значения Три не совпадают!!!
# Значение в контрольном списке 3000
# Значение в проверяемом списке 30000
```

> тут **ВАЖНО** обратить внимание на завершающий символ строки в том месте где используется `replace`. Поскольку если исходник сформирован в системе Windows то имеется большая вероятность того, что окончание строки будет не `\n` а `\r\n` и в результате проверяемое значение будет выглядеть как (к примеру) `2000\r` после удаления `\n`

Comment: Думаю, для новичка, это сложное и не совсем понятное решение.

Comment: @Brainofmadness, думаю, что новичок, если ему будет непонятно, спросит "как это у тебя работает?" или попробует разобраться самостоятельно. В решении нет ничего заоблачно сложного, я сам не Гвидо нифига.